# Nested anonymous functions matlab

Tags: matlab

I'd like to nest these two anonymous functions but I'm not sure I set it up correctly. Any thoughts?

```
% part 1
z = @(y,w,k)(-1*(y*w'*k));

% part 2
ePart = @(y,w,k) exp(z(y,w,k));

ePart(YY,WW,KK); % error... K not found
```

Comment: It works when I copy & paste the code

Comment: Is `k` (small letter) or `KK` not found (in the error message)? The setup looks good to me. If `YY`, `WW` and `KK` are properly defined, there should be no issue.

Comment: `epart` is not same as `ePart`

Comment: note: unless you actually want a complex conjugate, use `w.'` (instead of `w'`) to get a real `transpose` operator.

Comment: @Hoki Well said! :-)

Comment: What is the actual entire error message?